# Is there a Heart Rate Tracker that can be directly connected from a developed app?

Tags: android, wear-os, heartbeat

I'm looking for a wearable device, which can monitor heart rate. Fitbit does not allow developer to directly connect (Bluetooth connection) to the device, but request using their API.

I have my logging app (Android), and I would like to collect heart rate from wearable device by connecting it to my app without API stuff. I don't want user to be complicated due to some authorization processes. I have been searching smart bands/watches, but I haven't seen a device that is able to do aforementioned things.

I would be grateful if you recommend me some wearable devices.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use

- SensorManager
- Sensor
- sensorEventListener.

I use(Hardware):

- Pollar M600
- LG G4
- LG Urbane watch